# Axway Appceletator Studio doesn't work (after holiday)

Tags: windows, titanium, appcelerator

After holiday, Axway Appceleretor Studio no longer works under Windows (under Mac yes).
Studio returns this error:

```
[INFO] :   
[INFO] :   Alloy compiled in 0.84305s
[INFO] :   Alloy compiler completed successfully
[INFO] :   Starting Hyperloop assembly
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating system metabase
2018-01-08T14:43:04.838Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
spawn javac ENOENT
2018-01-08T14:43:04.838Z | ERROR  | spawn javac ENOENT
2018-01-08T14:43:04.839Z | TRACE  | Error: spawn javac ENOENT
at _errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
---------------------------------------------
at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:305:13)
at exports.spawn (child_process.js:502:9)
at compileIfNecessary (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\modules\android\hyperloop\3.0.1\hooks\metabase\metabase.js:41:6)
at generate (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\modules\android\hyperloop\3.0.1\hooks\metabase\metabase.js:77:2)
at generateJSON (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\modules\android\hyperloop\3.0.1\hooks\metabase\metabase.js:110:2)
at Object.loadMetabase (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\modules\android\hyperloop\3.0.1\hooks\metabase\metabase.js:168:3)
at Promise (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\modules\android\hyperloop\3.0.1\hooks\tasks\generate-metabase-task.js:53:22)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at GenerateMetabaseTask.runTaskAction (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\modules\android\hyperloop\3.0.1\hooks\tasks\generate-metabase-task.js:52:10)
```

Comment: Is this a problem when you open Studio? Or when you try to build an app?

Comment: There's a number of things that can cause this error. Perhaps javac is not in your PATH? Perhaps the javac executable is corrupt or wrong architecture for your OS?

Comment: appc logout/login from the terminal and then try it again?

Comment: It's a problem when i build application.

Comment: I tried logout/login but it's same.